# Where can I get gawk library of functions?

Tags: application-development

Using Xubuntu 11.10

I am learning gawk. I would like to get the gawk library of functions mentioned in the gawk users guide. The guide mentions extracting it from the gawk.texi with `extract.awk`, but I find that a bit too hard.

Is there a place where I can just download it?

Answer (score 1):

The gawk package on Ubuntu includes the library functions mentioned in the manual. You can find a number of them in `/usr/share/awk` and the rest in `/usr/share/doc/gawk/examples`.

Answer (score 0):

When you're wondering where to get a command in modern ubuntu distros just try to run it at the command line and you'll get something like this:

```
username@hostname:~$ gawk
The program 'gawk' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install gawk
```